# python 3.5 appending .txt file not formatting correctly when opened in notepad

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to append to a text file and write on a new line each time I append the file for readability in notepad.  I believe this should be simple and researched thoroughly but I am still having an issue.  Here is the snippet of code that writes to a .txt file:

```
appending_Text = data2
with open(file_Name, 'a+') as file:
    file.write(appending_Text)
    file.write('\n')
```

When I run this code and then check the text file, I get my appended data on the same line.  When I open the .txt file using notepad, I want it to look like:

```
data1
data2
```

When I open the .txt file using notepad in windows, it looks like:

```
data1data2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer and it's not python related but rather a limitation of notepad in windows.  Notepad uses a different new line termination than is used in linux systems.  Linux uses '\n' and notepad uses '/r/n'